# How to change TTY screen refresh rate?

Tags: kernel, display, amdgpu

Linux starts at 60 hz, but Xorg goes up to 144. Monitor has to restart itself which obviously takes ages.
I guess it's a minor problem, but it might help me solve a couple more.

GPU is r9 390x, using AMDGPU drivers.